# Err0r while using 0pen CV Gaussian blur

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I have a multi-page `.tif` file and I need to extract text from it. I am trying to apply the `Gaussian blur` to improve it's quality and then applying `Tesseract OCR` to extract the text. I am getting below error during applying the Gaussian blur

> TypeError: src data type = 0 is not supported

**Code**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
import numpy as np
import pycountry
import cv2

with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    img = Image.open('sample.tif')

    for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(img)):
        page2 = np.asarray(page)

        # Gaussian Blur
        imgG = cv2.GaussianBlur(page2, (5,5), 0)  # <---- ERROR

        # Tesseract OCR
        api.SetImage(imgG)
        text = api.GetUTF8Text()
```

Comment: Try debugging `print imgG.shape` and `print imgG.dtype` before gaussian blur.

Comment: @ZdaR You meant `print page2.shape` and `print page2.dtype`

Comment: @ZdaR Output is `(3507, 2480)` and `bool` respectively

Comment: OpenCV will not work with boolean arrays. Plus, I'm not sure Gaussian Blur means anything with boolean input/output. Try either converting to float by multiplying your array with 1.0, or using 255*page2.astype(np.uint8)

Comment: @Ben Hi, after this line `page2 = 255*page2.astype(np.uint8)` I am getting error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'` at `api.SetImage(imgG)`

Comment: My guess is that the SetImage function from tesserocr expects a PIL image as an input, but you give it a numpy array. Have a look at the docs to check the input and output of functions you use, and refactor your code accordingly.